# Submit to store fails with "failed validation"

Tags: xcode, app-store

I am seeing the following issue when submitting my app to the app store via XCode 4.2:

An error occurred uploading to the iTunes store.

I click "finish" and in the organizer, the status is 
"Failed validation"

- This is an app i have submitted to the store a dozen times successfully.
- I did recently convert to it a universal build to support both iphone and ipad.  I did add all of the requisite icons and splash screen images based on apple's required list
- I upped the deployment target to ios 4.0 from 3.2
- The application runs fine as an adhoc build on real iphone and ipads.

that error message doesn't give me much to go on.  Is there any way to get more info about what validation failed?  the log is clear

Comment: You didn't get any more than that? Anytime I have seen "Failed validation" it continues with "...because of the following issues"

Comment: i figured it out.  Had something to do with needing to update java to the latest.  I guess they broke something.  Why the xcode app loader uses java ill never know.there's 1.5 days of my life i'd like back >.<

Comment: I'm suddenly getting the same problem as you. I've submitted tens and tens of apps and suddenly I get this. I don' get it. :-P Though I realize I do have a pending Java update here. Hope it fixes it. Because like you I only get that same vague "Failed validation" error.

Comment: It worked. Actually I got me another Macintosh the other day - it had all the Java updates in there so I just tried submitting with that box and bingo. That java update was probably it. Well I guess XCode really builds on that old Java IDE Eclipse - which in itself was built on Java. Not sure XCode 4.x still is however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run apples latest java updates to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What usually works for me :

- Retry validating
- Clean and rebuild (the re-validate)